# A disc is cut into 12 sectors with areas in arithmetic progression. The largest angle is twice the smallest. Find the smallest angle.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

I was given a question which states -

> *A circular disc is cut into twelve sectors whose areas are in an
>   arithmetic sequence. The angle of the largest sector is twice the
>   angle of the smallest sector.*
>
> *Find the size of the angle of the smallest sector.*

Here's what I have done so far,

$\Rightarrow U_1 = w$

$\Rightarrow U_n = 2w$

$\Rightarrow w + (n - 1)d = 2w$

$\Rightarrow n = 12$

$\therefore\ d = \frac{w}{11}$

And now I am clueless about where to go from here...

Comment: In the last equation, surely you mean
$$
d= \frac{w}{11}
$$
so now $d$ is the increment between the different terms. The next step is to write an expression for the sum of the sectors. On the other hand, the total angle is $360^{\circ}$ (or $2\pi$), and on the other hand it's the sum of the arithmetic sequence. Please write this as an equation.

Comment: @MattiP. - I'm so sorry, you're right. Must have made that mistake in a hurry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the sum of twelve sectors is the whole disc,
$$360^{\circ}=\sum_{k=1}^{12} (w+(k-1)d)=12w+d\sum_{k=1}^{12}(k-1)=12w+66d$$
which, together with $w + (12 - 1)d = 2w$, i.e. $11d=w$ give you all you need to find $w$, that is the angle (in degrees) of the smallest sector:
$$360^{\circ}=12w+66d=12w+6w\implies w=\frac{360^\circ}{18}=20^\circ.$$

Comment: I tried this and I get the answer $w = 20$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, $w=360^{\circ}/18=20^{\circ}$.

Comment: Well, thanks a bunch! I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You got $d = a$<sub>1</sub>$/11$.

($a$<sub>1</sub> is angle of the smallest sector)

We can write: $11d = a$<sub>1</sub>   ........(1)

Now, we know:

Area of sector = ${\frac{1}2}.{r^2}.\theta$

And,

Sum of area of all sectors = Area of circle

(${\frac{1}2}.{r^2}.a$<sub>1</sub>) + (${\frac{1}2}.{r^2}.a$<sub>2</sub>) + ..... + (${\frac{1}2}.{r^2}.a$<sub>12</sub>) = $\pi.r^2$

${\frac{1}2}.r^2$.{ $a$<sub>1</sub> + $a$<sub>2</sub> + ..... + $a$<sub>12</sub> } = $\pi.r^2$

$a$<sub>1</sub> + $a$<sub>2</sub> + ..... + $a$<sub>12</sub> = 2$\pi$

Applying the formula for the sum of $n$ terms of an AP:

${\frac{12}2}.${ $2a$<sub>1</sub> + $(12-1).d$ } = 2$\pi$

$6$.{ $2a$<sub>1</sub> + $11d$ } = 2$\pi$

Putting value of $11d$ from (1):

$6$.{ $2a$<sub>1</sub> + $a$<sub>1</sub> } = 2$\pi$

$a$<sub>1</sub> = $\frac{\pi}9$

Comment: Amazing answer. This is very helpful. Just to confirm, is $\frac{\pi}9$ equal to $20$ in degrees?

Comment: Yes it's 20 in degrees, as π = 180∘

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the formula -

> ## $\frac{n}{2}(U_1 + U_n)$

Like this,

$\Rightarrow\ \frac{12}{2}(w^{\circ} + 2w^{\circ}) = 360^{\circ}$

$\Rightarrow\ 6(3w^{\circ}) = 360^{\circ}$

$\Rightarrow\ w^{\circ}  = \frac{360^{\circ}}{18}$

$\therefore\ w^{\circ} = 20^{\circ}$

Comment: This is the right answer: ignore the differences and jump straight to the sum.

Comment: @Justin I realise now that you accepted your own answer... I thought that this was not possible here, but I was wrong.
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21221/accepting-your-own-answer